# Drawing a simple circle

Tags: java, geometry

I'm trying to draw a circle with the help of Java but I'm stuck
This is what I've done so far,

```
public class Circle {
public static void DrawMeACircle(int posX, int posY, int radius) {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 10;

    int x = posX - a; //x = position of x away from the center
    int y = posY - b;
    int xSquared = (x - a)*(x - a);
    int ySquared = (y - b)*(y - b);
    for (int i = 0;i <=20; i++) {
        for (int j = 1;j <=20; j++) {
            if (Math.abs(xSquared) + (ySquared) >= radius*radius && Math.abs(xSquared) + (ySquared) <= radius*radius) {
                    System.out.println("#");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    DrawMeACircle(5,5,5);



    }
```

}

As you can see, this doesn't work out properly. Does anyone know how this can be solved?
I'm thankful for any help possible, Michael.

Comment: If you dig further into graphics and need to continue drawing circles, check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your inner `if` condition does not depend from `i` and `j`, so is a constant. That means the same symbol is printed every time, a space symbol.

Next, you're using `System.out.println(" ");` every time, adding a newline to each symbol. So, result looks like a column of spaces.

Last, but not least: drawing area is limited by 20x20 "pixels" and unable to fit large circles.

You can fix all these points together with something like

```
public class Circle {
public static void DrawMeACircle(int posX, int posY, int radius) {
    for (int i = 0;i <= posX + radius; i++) {
       for (int j = 1;j <=posY + radius; j++) {
            int xSquared = (i - posX)*(i - posX);
            int ySquared = (j - posY)*(j - posY);
            if (Math.abs(xSquared + ySquared - radius * radius) < radius) {
                System.out.print("#");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    DrawMeACircle(5,15,5);
}
}
```

which gives us somewhat similar to the circle.